# Advantages and Disadvantages of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can any one tell the advantages and disadvantages using angularJS framework?

when we need to use this framework.

Comment: Why did you tag this as Java?

Comment: Lots of blog post are available on internet. Like
http://blog.softelegance.com/angularjs/angularjs-advantages-and-limitations/
http://how-to-angular.blogspot.in/2015/01/advantagesdisadvantages-of-angular-js.html
https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-the-AngularJS-JavaScript-MVC-framework

Answer (score 7):

Some of the AngularJS advantages are given below:

1. Two-way data-binding
2. Directives
3. Client side MVC framework
4. Dependency Injection
5. Filters
6. Templating

Lots of blog posts are also available if you search for "*angularjs advantages and disadvantages*"; here are some links:

- http://javaelegance.blogspot.jp/2015/11/advantage-disadvantage-of-angularjs.html
- http://blog.softelegance.com/angularjs/angularjs-advantages-and-limitations/
- http://how-to-angular.blogspot.in/2015/01/advantagesdisadvantages-of-angular-js.html
- https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-the-AngularJS-JavaScript-MVC-framework?share=1